# Close all open forms except for some VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, openform

as the title, I am trying to close all open forms except some in VB.Net but the forms don't close.
Here is the code I used:

```
Dim lista As New FormCollection
lista = Application.OpenForms
For Each a As Form In lista
    If Not a.Text = "formLogout" And a.Text = "arresto" And a.Text = "riavvio" And a.Text = "formOpen" Then
        a.Close()
    End If
Next
scrivania.Close()
Me.Close()
```

Grazie.

Comment: Your expression is [parsed as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference//operators/operator-precedence#logical-and-bitwise-operators) `If (Not (a.Text = "formLogout")) And (a.Text = "arresto") And (a.Text = "riavvio") And (a.Text = "formOpen") Then` which is always false.

Comment: @GSerg: Thank you for emphasizing the importance of associativity in boolean expressions. In my opinion the usage of parenthesises _should be mandatory_.

Comment: @GSerg I tried with parenthesises but it don't work.

Comment: @HelloXD I did not tell you to try with parentheses. I showed (with the help of parentheses) how your expression is *currently* parsed.

Comment: Saying `Dim lista As New FormCollection` on one line (emphasis on the "New") and `lista = somethingelse` on the next demonstrates a core misunderstanding of how the language handles object references vs object instances.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, strange - this symptom are very very common for vb.net developers, but I don't remember it in c# ;)

Comment: @Fabio Honestly, at this point they ought to create  _and document_ (so you can count on it) a compiler optimization for this scenario, so the extra allocation never takes place. I'll be surprised if the former doesn't happen (at least) at JIT-time anyway, but it could also be guaranteed.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - so more arguing during code reviews :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If` statement will return true **when all provided conditions are true**, which is not possible because you compare same `form.Text` with different values.
Notice that in your example `Not` will be applied only for the first condition

You possibly can rewrite condition as follow:

```
If Not (form.Text = "formLogout" OrElse form.Text = "arresto") Then ..
```

Suggest to use a collection of form names, which should not be closed

```
Dim remainOpenForms As New HashSet(Of String)
remainOpenForms.Add("formLogout")
remainOpenForms.Add("arresto")

' Create collection of forms to be closed
Dim formsToClose As New List(Of Form)
For Each form As Form In Application.OpenForms
    If remainOpenForms.Contains(form.Text) = False Then formsToClose.Add(form)
Next

For Each form As Form In formsToClose
    form.Close()
Next
```

Comment: It don't work. It also gave me an exception because the form collection was changed. @Fabio

Comment: @HelloXD, true, you cannot close forms during iteration of `ApplicationOpenForms`, because form will be removed from it when closed. Check updated answer.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for introduction to HashSet. It has some very interesting methods.

Answer (score 2):

Same as @Fabio 's answer without the extra collection and loop.

```
    Dim keepOpen As New List(Of String) From {Me.Text, Form2.Text, Form3.Text}
    For index = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Not keepOpen.Contains(Application.OpenForms(index).Text) Then
            Application.OpenForms(index).Close()
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Or you can use `For Each form As Form in Application.OpenForms.Reverse()`

Comment: @Fabio Having a red squiggle under Application.OpenForms.Reverse(). Although it should implement IEnumerable it is a read only property. Would that mean it cannot use .Reverse?

Comment: `For Each form As Form In Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form).Reverse()` Linq extesions are applied to specific collection types. `OfType()` returns an `IEnumerable`, `OpenForms` doesn't.

Comment: @Jimi Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced form.**toString** with form.**Name** from Fabio's solution, and it worked like a charm!

```
    Try
        Dim remainOpenForms As New HashSet(Of String)
        remainOpenForms.Add("FormMainMenu")

        Dim formsToClose As New List(Of Form)
        For Each form As Form In Application.OpenForms
            If Not remainOpenForms.Contains(form.Name) Then
                formsToClose.Add(form)
                Debug.Print("closing: " & form.Name)
            Else
                Debug.Print("keep open: " & form.Name)
            End If
        Next

        For Each form As Form In formsToClose
            form.Close()
        Next

        Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteErrors("FMM: WAN2", ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

*In case your wondering why I closed it after: I received an InvalidOperationException Collection was modified. This is my Exit application module*

Answer (score 0):

i know its to late but for some here is my answer

what this does is close all form except "exceptthisform"

```
     Dim formNames As New List(Of String)

        For Each currentForm As Form In Application.OpenForms

            If currentForm.Name <> "exceptthisform" Then

                formNames.Add(currentForm.Name)

            End If

        Next

        For Each currentFormName As String In formNames
            Application.OpenForms(currentFormName).Close()

        Next
```